# ITicketStore AuthenticationTicket ExpiresUtc value always 14 days

Tags: c#, authentication, token, openid-connect, adfs

I'm creating a custom ticket store that inherits from `ITicketStore` in order to store user tokens in a database since cookies were getting far too large due to saving tokens.

I've got everything setup and working, however, I cannot get the value of `ExpiresUtc` to be anything other than 14 days in the `AuthenticationTicket` that is passed into the `ITicketStore StoreAsync` method.

Looking at my ADFS instance, I've got refresh token lifetime down to 5 minutes and access token lifetime down to 2 minutes.  I am still unable to get the correct value stuffed into the `AuthenticationTicket`.

I've found I can manually change it once I'm in the `ITicketStore StoreAsync` method, however this isn't ideal since if the refresh token lifetime were to change on the ADFS, it would not be respected here.

Does ASP .net core set its own value for this?  Is ADFS setting the value itself and overriding my values?  What could be happening?

**STARTUP.CS**

```
    // Authentication / Authorization
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = Configuration["OpenIdConnect:Authority"];
        options.Resource = Configuration["OpenIdConnect:Resource"];
        options.ClientId = Configuration["OpenIdConnect:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["OpenIdConnect:ClientSecret"];

        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add(Configuration["OpenIdConnect:Scopes"]);
        options.SaveTokens = true;
                
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.SessionStore = new CustomTicketStore(services);
    });
```

**CustomTicketStore.CS**

```
public async Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
```

The CustomTicketStore was based around the following implementation:

https://ml-software.ch/posts/implementing-a-custom-iticketstore-for-asp-net-core-identity-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ExpiresUtc value is controlled by [CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpan](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d69a2253bb26b07290de3a7aa8d3bad54c610dfb/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs#L31) which defaults to 14 days.

[OpenIdConnectOptions.UseTokenLifetime](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d69a2253bb26b07290de3a7aa8d3bad54c610dfb/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs#L266-L271) can override this to make the expiration match the auth token.